# Windows Batch Variables Won't Set

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

I think I ran into a bug in Window's batch scripting.

I cannot set variables that are in an expanded if statement.

Here is an isolated part of my script:

```
@echo off

set success=1
set Version=12345
set Target=Client
set Type=456
set dir=
set zip=

if "%Version%"=="" set success=0
if "%Type%"=="" set success=0

if 1==1 set test=42

if %success%==1 (
    set test2=57005
    if "%Target%"=="Client" (
        set dir=ModName v%Version%
        set zip=ModName v%Version% %Type%.zip
        echo Version: %Version%
        echo    Type: %Type%
        echo.
        echo  Target: %Target%
        echo     dir: %dir%
        echo     zip: %zip%
        echo.
        echo    test: %test%
        echo   test2: %test2%
    )
) else (
    echo Not successful.
)
```

This is the output from a brand new instance of cmd:

```
C:\Users\RandomClown\Desktop>test.bat
Version: 12345
   Type: 456

 Target: Client
    dir:
    zip:

   test: 42
  test2:
```

What you should notice is that the single line if statement correctly sets stuff.
The multiline if will perform anything that is NOT a set. I dont think I missed anything.
Also, the multiline if statement is correctly executing the right lines, as the `else ( echo Not successful. )` lines did not execute.

Why did the lines not execute?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [windows batch SET inside IF not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102422/windows-batch-set-inside-if-not-working)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You missed something ;-)

`cmd` expands variables when commands are *parsed*, not when they are run. It so happens that an `if` or `for` statement with a block `( ... )` (or actually any block) counts as a single command in that case. So when you set variables inside a block *and* try using them in the same block there are no variables anymore – they were replaced by the values the variables had *before* the block even executed.

Stick a

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

at the start of your batch file and use `!zip!` instead of `%zip%`. See `help set` for a detailed discussion of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just a remind, the ms-dos "set" command takes every string after the equal sign. So if you write

```
if "x"=="x" set a=foo else set a=bar
echo %a%  // output : foo else set a=bar
```

The %a% is actually set to "foo else set a=bar", not foo. 
So I always use "()" for set command if there are multiple commands in one line.

```
if "%1"=="" (set a=20) else (set a=%1)
```

Comment: the "set" command doesn't always take every string after the equals sign. Example: set one=1 & echo Hiya. Good point about the parenthesis though, they are indeed super helpful.