# Read text file content into batch variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have files:
y:\a.txt
y:\b.txt

I have x.bat:

```
@echo off  
y:  
cd \  
for /f %%f in ('dir /b y:\*.txt') do (  
set content=  
set /p content=<y:\%%f  
echo y:\%%f  
echo content=%content%  
)
```

and the result:

```
y:\a.txt  
content=  
y:\b.txt  
content=
```

Why does not contain %content% variable the first lie of the text files? The files are not empty.

Comment: You need delayed expansion to use a variable within a loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Batch Variables Won't Set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set)

Comment: No. It does not work if I put setlocal enabledelayedexpansion at the start. Ruselts are the same...

Comment: You don't understand how to used delayed expansion.  You also need to use this line instead, as the `!` marks are how delayed expansion is utilised: `echo content=!content!` and to send a message to someone you have to use @foxidrive for example somewhere in the comment.  You get them automatically but I didn't know you had replied.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your batch script as follows:

```
@echo off  
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
y:\
cd \
set content=
for /f %%f in ('dir /b *.txt') do (  
set /p content=<%%~dpff
echo file:%%~dpff , content:!content!
)
```

**EDIT.** Note the `~dpf` to get the file path. As @foxidrive has mentioned it wouldn't have worked without a proper path.

The output is along the lines of:

```
file:y:\a.txt , content:lorem
file:y:\b.txt , content:ipsum
file:y:\c.txt , content:Ocaml, Haskell
```

Comment: It does not work. The system cannot find the file with !<y:\%%f!
It is interesting that set /p content= works without the for loop and it does not within the loop...