# batch function set does not work, why?

Tags: batch-file

the following should print false and then true
but instead it prints false and false
I debugged it a bit, and it seems like when the batch is in the if, the call woeks, but does not set res

why is that?

```
@echo off
set res=true
Call :IsSame None None1

if false==false (
    echo %res%
    Call :IsSame None2 None2
    echo %res%
)

GOTO :EOF
:IsSame 
echo isSame
set res=false
if %~2==All (
    set res=true
    goto :EOF
)
if %~2==%~1 (
    set res=true
    goto :EOF
)
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch Variables Won't Set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line to `echo on` and you will see on execution that `%res%` is replaced by `cmd.exe` immediately on batch file start by the string `false` and not changed anymore.

The solution is using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` as explained for example in help of command **set** which can be viewed by entering in a command prompt window `set /?`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set res=true
Call :IsSame None None1

if false==false (
    echo old: %res%, new: !res!
    Call :IsSame None2 None2
    echo old: %res%, new: !res!
)

GOTO :EOF
:IsSame 
echo isSame
set res=false
if %~2==All (
    set res=true
    goto :EOF
)
if %~2==%~1 (
    set res=true
    goto :EOF
)
goto :EOF
```

The second line enables now delayed expansion for environment variables.

And there are now twice `!res!` additionally to `%res%` to demonstrate the difference between delayed and not delayed expansion. Thanks [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) for this suggestion.

Comment: even better: the echo after the `call` could be: `echo old: %res%, new: !res!` to show both values.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of small errors in your code.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET res=false
CALL :IsSame None None

IF false==false (
    ECHO %res%
    CALL :IsSame None2 None
    ECHO %res%
)

GOTO EOF
:IsSame 
ECHO isSame
SET res = false;
if %~2==All (
    ECHO number1
    SET res=true
    GOTO:EOF
)
if %~2==%~1 (
    SET res=true
    ECHO %res%
    GOTO:EOF
)
GOTO:EOF
:EOF
```

Comment: See the Microsoft articles about [goto](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490914.aspx) and [if](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490920.aspx) to understand that `goto :EOF` without a label `EOF` is right. And there should be always a space between command `goto` and name of the label without the colon, except for `goto :EOF` although `cmd.exe` interprets also `goto:label` correct. Syntactically 100% correct is nevertheless only `goto label`.

Comment: @Mofi, perhaps I am too used to the old-fashioned DOS batch code :) I've always used GOTO:EOF for subroutines because it looked 'cleaner' than GOTO :EOF, which just looks like a mistake in a regular goto command.