# batch file remove X characters of filename

Tags: batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename

I did batch file which copy 3 files and need to rename it by removing last 33 characters. The copy works fine but removing last 33 characters not... I saw more then one answer on web and try it all but nothing work so far.

My batch file look like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ("my folder")  do (
    ren "%%i" "%i:~0,-33%".txt
)
```

I tried already:

```
set fName=%%i
ren "%fName%" "%fName:~0,-33%.txt"
```

Comment: another error for trying :
set FOLDER_PATH=XXXX
for %%f in (%FOLDER_PATH%*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    ren "%%f" "!filename:~0,-33!%%~xf"
)

the system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Do the `%fname%` one again, but use [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set) this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information I got here, try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "folderpath=[Your Folder Here...]"
cd %folderpath%
for /f %%a in ('dir /b "*.txt"') do (
   set "fname=%%~na"
   ren "%%a" "!fname:~0,-33!.txt"
)
endlocal
```

This is similar to the answer above. You should make sure the batch file is OUTSIDE the folder.

**EDIT.** 
When dealing with variables formed inside FOR and IF's, use delayed expansion (i.e. !var!, instead of %var%). Anyway, this is the fixed code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

::NO Last Backslash...
set "sourcepath=C:\Users\tzahi.k\Desktop\testSource\source2"
set "folderpath=C:\Users\tzahi.k\Desktop\testSource\des"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /od "%sourcepath%\*.txt"') do (
   set "youngest=%%a"
   xcopy /y "%sourcepath%\!youngest!" "%folderpath%"
)

cd /d %folderpath%
for /f %%a in ('dir /b "*.txt"') do (
    set "fname=%%~na"
    ren "%%a" "!fname:~0,-33!.txt"
)
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: now i've got different problem...this code works fine alone but when i put it under my copy code its stop working
look like this
set folderpath=C:\Users\tzahi.k\Desktop\testSource\des
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir  /b /od "C:\Users\tzahi.k\Desktop\testSource\source2\*.txt"') do set Youngest=%%a

xcopy /y "C:\Users\tzahi.k\Desktop\testSource\source2\%Youngest%" %folderpath%

cd %folderpath%
for /f %%a in ('dir /b "%folderpath%\*.txt"') do (
   set "fname=%%~na"
   ren "%%a" "!fname:~0,-33!.txt"
)
pause

Answer (score 0):

Here's the batch file you'd want to run:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

@for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.txt')  do (
    set fname=%%~ni
    set fname=!fname:~0,-33!.txt
    ren "%%i" "!fname!"
)

endlocal
```

Comment: thanks
but now i've got another error says Access is denied...
any suggestion?

Comment: Hard to tell, but if you originally copied your files from a network or shared folder, the read-only attribute may have been set by the copy operation on the destination files. You could start the batch file with a **attrib -r *.txt** command just to make sure.

Comment: What works only for the first file? The batch file or the Attrib command? What errors do you get after the first file? Still _Access Denied_? Where did you add the **attrib** command in the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set FOLDER_PATH=C:\Some\Path\
for %%f in (%FOLDER_PATH%*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    ren "%%f" "!filename:~0,-33!%%~xf"
)
PAUSE
```

Or better this

```
@echo off & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
set F=%%~Na
set F=!F:~0,33!
move /y "%%a" "!F!%%~Xa"
)
```