# Batch: how to run http server in every drive path?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This is a batch script to run httpserver in every drive path if drive exists to list its files. in this script `set /a %port%` is not working.

```
@echo off
set /a port=8080
for %%i in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do if exist %%i: (
cd /d %%i:\
start SimpleHTTPServer.exe %port%
set /a port+=1
)
```

Comment: How about patching `SimpleHTTPServer.exe` to create `JustSlightlyMoreComplicatedHTTPServer.exe` that can actually serve multiple directories from one process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch Variables Won't Set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set)

Comment: Also, -1 until you ask a more meaningful question than "why isn't it working?"

Comment: @Kaz `I was doing that in python but i was checking with batch first.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how environment variables are expanded inside of blocks in a batch file.  To override this behavior, use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!` instead of `%` to reference the environment variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a port=8080
for %%i in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do if exist %%i: (
cd /d %%i:\
start SimpleHTTPServer.exe !port!
set /a port+=1
)
```

Comment: Thank you buddy, so nice of you!