# %errorlevel% returning 0 in loop command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Ok, I've installed Dropbox but it didn't corresponded to what I was looking for so I uninstalled it with Revo Pro.
But, when i open the taskmanager there are still processes related to it running in my computer so I decided to make a batch to look out and delete all files that are related to it.

```
    @echo off
    cd c:\
    :a
    set /p a=Phrase that might be realted to it 

    for /r %%d IN (*.*) DO (
        (
        findstr /i /m /c:%a% "%%d"
        if "%errorlevel%"=="0" del "%%d"
        echo %errorlevel%
        )
    )

    pause
```

The problem is: when I run findstr using loop even when there is no match for my variable "%a%" in an analized file %errorlevel% returns as 0. But when I use findstr alone and there isn't a match %ERRORLEVEL% returns as 1 and 0 for a match.
If I use it, I'll delete all my PC files haha. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch Variables Won't Set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set)

Comment: variables in blocks are evaluated only once. you must use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and change `%errorlevel%` to `!errorlevel!` to get the value evaluated for each iteration.

Comment: You can't delete the executable of of running process so your script won't do anything to about the processes that are still running. Try rebooting your computer and see if they go away. If it doesn't, try reinstalling Dropbox and then uninstalling properly by using its own uninstaller, rather than some third party program.

Answer (score 2):

Within a parenthesised series of statements, any `%var%` is replaced by the value of that variable at the time the verb controlling that statement-sequence (or `block`) is encountered.

Here, the block is the entire sequence of statements controlled by the `for`. `%errorlevel%` is replaced by the status of `errorlevel` at the time the `for` is encountered, so probably `0`.

If you use

```
    findstr /i /m /c:%a% "%%d"
    if not errorlevel 1 del "%%d"
    echo %errorlevel%
```

then the `run-time` value of `errorlevel` is used (ie. as it changes through the operation of the loop) and the command means "if `errorlevel` is not (1 **or greater than 1**) do this..."

The `findstr` will set `errorlevel` to 0 on `found`, `1` on `not found` and `2` for `file not found`(IIRC) so NOT (1 or greater than 1) selects 0 only. Note that in certain esoteric circumstances, `errorlevel` may become negative, but after a `findstr` I believe 0..2 is the allowed range.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's wrong with the code, but you can probably skip it using the && operand.

```
 findstr /i /m /c:%a% "%%d" && del "%%d" echo %errorlevel%
```

Thanks to Stephan for correcting the example.

Comment: Oh thanks for the help. But, what exactly is the && operant?

Comment: @AdrianoAraujo: see [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). It works as "if previous command was successful, then". Galra: `&&` followed by `if %errorlevel%==0` makes no sense. use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Windows command interpreter encounters `(` being interpreted as begin of a command block, it parses the entire command block up to matching `)` marking end of the command block and replaces all `%variable%` by current value of the variable.

This means in this case that before command **FOR** is the first time executed, everything from `(` after **DO** up to last `)` is processed already with replacing all `%variable%` references by current value of the appropriate variable. Then the already preprocessed block is executed one (on command **IF**) or more times (on command **FOR**).

This behavior can be seen by debugging the batch file. For debugging a batch file first `@echo off` must be removed or commented out with command **REM** or changed to `@echo on`. Then a command prompt window must be opened and the batch file is executed from within this command prompt window by typing its name with full path enclosed in double quotes if path or name contains a space character. The Windows command interpreter shows now all command lines and command blocks after preprocessing before executing and of course the standard messages and the error messages output by the commands or by Windows command interpreter itself in case of a syntax error in batch file.

Opening a command prompt window means running `cmd.exe` with option `/K` to **Keep** window open after execution of a command or a batch script. Double clicking on a batch file starts also `cmd.exe` for processing the batch file, but with parameter `/C` to **Close** the window automatically after batch processing terminated independent on cause - successful finished or an error occurred.

The command prompt window opened before running the batch file remains open after batch processing finished successfully or with an error except the batch file contains command **EXIT** without parameter `/B`. So experts in batch code writing test batch files always by running them from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on them.

Delayed variable expansion is needed for variables set or modified and referenced within same command block as explained by help of command **SET** output on running in a command prompt window `set /?`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /D C:\
:a
set /P "a=Phrase that might be realted to it: "

for /r %%d in (*) do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /i /m /c:"%a%" "%%d"
    if "!errorlevel!" == "0" del "%%d" >nul
)
endlocal
```

But for checking the exit code of a previous command there is also `if errorlevel` syntax as explained by Microsoft in support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /D C:\
:a
set /P "a=Phrase that might be realted to it: "

for /r %%d in (*) do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /i /m /c:"%a%" "%%d" >nul
    if not errorlevel 1 del "%%d" >nul
)
endlocal
```

`if errorlevel X` tests if exit code of previous command or application when it modifies the errorlevel variable at all is greater or equal `X`. By using `if not errorlevel X` the check is if last exit code is lower than `X` which is here a test if exit code is 0.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`

And see also

- [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands)
- [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)
- Answer on question [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564)