# Perform arithmetic in loop with variables in Batch

Tags: batch-file, variables, for-loop, echo, arithmetic-expressions

I would like to print the following:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

I have tried this:

```
ECHO OFF
FOR /L %%A in (1,1,5) DO (
    SET /a "B=%%A-1"
    ECHO %B%
)
```

However, this gives me:

```
4
4
4
4
4
```

How can I achieve the desired output while using both `A` and `B` in my code?

Comment: This is a delayed expansion problem.  Too lazy to google it, but there are hundreds of questions like this on SO already.  Why not just `for /L %%A in (0,1,4)`?  If that's not practical, then you should `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `echo !B!`.  For more info, do `help set` in a cmd console, paying attention to the section beginning "Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been added."

Comment: That code does not output a **4** five times. It will output `ECHO IS OFF` five times.

Comment: @Squashman It output `ECHO IS OFF` five times the first time I ran it, but ouput `4` five times the next time I ran it.

Comment: That's because you ran it a second time without closing the cmd prompt (on a related note, good on you for running the script from the command prompt instead of double-clicking it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch Variables Won't Set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ECHO OFF
setlocal
FOR /L %%A in (1,1,5) DO (
    SET /a "B=%%A-1"
    call ECHO %%B%%
)
```

Since you are not using `setlocal`, `B` will be set to the value from the previous run. `%B%` will be replaced by `4` since `B` was set to `4` by the previous run. the `call echo` trick uses a parsing quirk to retrieve the current (run-time) value of the variable.

Here's "the official" way:

```
ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%A in (1,1,5) DO (
    SET /a "B=%%A-1"
    ECHO !B!
)
```

In `delayedexpansion` mode, `!var!` retrieves the value of `var` as it changes at run-time. This is not without its drawbacks, but you'd need to read up on `delayedexpansion` for a guide on that matter.

Comment: batch is such a pain