# Variable value not showing in Win Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, adb

I am writing a batch to automate the installation of a a number of settings, INI files and APKs on a multitude of devices. I am getting errors in the batch due to the variables in showing **NULL**.

I have checked that the **config.ini** and **ADBCommands.ini** and **adb+.bat** are in the correct location.

Can you help?

```
::Global
@echo off
cd C:\

::INI Locations
set mypath=%~dp0
set config=%mypath%config.ini
set Commands=%mypath%ADBCommands.ini
set multi=%mypath%adb+.bat
@pause

::Set Varialbes
@for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (%config%) do (
if %%a==Build set Build=%%b
if %%a==Version set Version=%%b
if %%a==Creator set Creator=%%b
if %%a==DateModified set DateModified=%%b
if %%a==ScreenTimeout set ScreenTimeout=%%b
if %%a==UnknownSources set UnknownSources=%%b
if %%a==ScreenBrightness set ScreenBrightness=%%b
)

@for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%d in (%Commands%) do (
if %%d==ScreenTimeoutCommand set ScreenTimeoutCommand=%%e
if %%d==UnknownSourcesCommand set UnknownSourcesCommand=%%e
if %%d==ScreenBrightnessCommand set ScreenBrightnessCommand=%%e
if %%d==OpenSOTICommand set OpenSOTICommand=%%e
)

::Build information
cls
@echo.
@echo.
@echo      BUILD:              %Build%
@echo      VERSION:            %Version%
@echo      BUILD CREATOR:      %Creator%
@echo      LAST UPDATED:       %DateModified%
@echo.
@echo.
@pause
```

Contents the ini files
**config.ini**

```
Build=XCover 3
Version=1.0.0
Creator=James B
DateModified=20/02/2017
ScreenTimeout=300000
UnknownSources=1
ScreenBrightness=225
```

Contents the ini files
**ADBCommands.ini**

```
ScreenTimeoutCommand=shell settings put system screen_off_timeout
UnknownSourcesCommand=shell settings put system install_non_market_apps
OpenSOTICommand=shell am start -n net.soti.mobicontrol.elm.samsung/net.soti.mobicontrol.startup.SplashActivity
```

Comment: ¿have you checked the files permissions?

Comment: All files have full system and user permissions

Comment: You do not need to set your FOR meta variables to environmental variables to use them.  Just use the FOR meta variables directly.  Also, you already have echo off, so you do not need to precede all your commands with the @.  Also, I am not understanding why you are using: `cmd.exe /c` to execute your FOR commands.

Comment: Regardless of the above, this is a lot of code to troubleshoot and none of us will be able to replicate your configuration.  You will have to tell us the exact lines of code you are having problems with.

Comment: `%Build%` `%Version%` `%Creator%` and  `%DateModified%` variables are showing nothing.

Comment: @Squashman i put in the `cmd.exe /c` as the ADB+.bat was closing the batch file before completion

Comment: You need to use the CALL command when executing ADB+.bat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch Variables Won't Set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set)

Comment: Without seeing the contents of the config and commands files, it would be difficult to troubleshoot what the two FOR commands are doing to those files.

Comment: @Squashman see edit

Comment: Does the mypath variable have spaces?

Comment: @Squashman yes it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your path has spaces you need to enclose the path with quotes. But when you do this, you need to tell the FOR /F command that you are still parsing a file and not a variable.  So you need to use the USEBACKQ option.

```
@for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ("%config%") do (
```

AND

```
@for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%d in ("%Commands%") do (
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks very much