# Error Handling in .bat File

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, sqlplus

I have a .bat file which runs two SQL files and moves files around. I need to have some error handling in this .bat file. I want it to take the error generated in sql and pass it into AutoSys
I was provided with this code:

```
#!/bin/sh 
. $HOME/.bash_profile

sqlplus -s $AUTOSYS_DB_USER/$AUTOSYS_DB_PASSWD <<!
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 999;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;
alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MM/YYYY';
execute P_LOST_APPROVALS;
!

exit_code=$?
if [ $exit_code != 0 ]; then
echo "Error calling sqlplus, return code = " $exit_code
exit $exit_code
fi

exit 0
```

However, I need it to run in .bat file and not Linux?

I currently have:

```
echo exit | sqlplus -s %CONNECT% @Code.sql 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
echo Unsuccessful
goto @ERROR_HANDLING_SQL
)
```

Full .bat file:

```
@echo off
call config.bat
SET CONNECT=%var1%/%var2%@avpr.world

Pushd  Location


Set SCRIPTPATH=Location
Set RESULTPATH=Location


echo exit | sqlplus -s %CONNECT% @Code.sql
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
echo Unsuccessful
goto @ERROR_HANDLING_SQL
)


echo exit | sqlplus -s %CONNECT% @createTXT.sql > File%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%.txt
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
echo Unsuccessful
goto @ERROR_HANDLING_SQL
 )



move "File%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%.txt" %RESULTPATH%


echo exit | sqlplus -s %CONNECT% @dropTable.sql
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
echo Unsuccessful
goto @ERROR_HANDLING_SQL
)



 : ERROR_HANDLING_SQL
 <echo -1>

pause
Exit
```

Comment: `I have a .bat file` I don't see any batch code in your question

Comment: Please change your question title and description and remove the batch-file tag.  This has nothing to do with Windows batch-files.

Comment: Full bat file provided

Comment: Remove the `@` prefixes in the `goto @Label` command lines, then write labels like `:Label` (no space between `:` and label name)...

Comment: @E_McAndrew I've edited my answer. Also I see you've added a batch-script in your post. If what you "currently have" came from my solution please report it. For the moment it looks like I didn't answer your question but just copied your code.

Comment: @J.Baoby The code I ended up using was from a similar job that we have running. Although the code is quite similar, I actually took it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An equivalent for the exit code `$?` in batch is the [errorlevel](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) accessible via the variable `%ERRORLEVEL%`. In batch scripting, there exists a special form of the IF-clause that uses the errorlevel: `IF ERRORLEVEL n` is equivalent to: "*if the errorlevel is **greater or equal to n**"*. As in bash, a value of 0 means the previous command executed without errors (not always, some commands don't set the errorlevel). So you have two choices:

1. `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0` which is the literal translation of your if-statement in your bash script. Be aware you'll have to use the [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) version `IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0` inside code blocks delimited with `(...)` (check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set/9681923#9681923) that explains why)
2. `IF ERRORLEVEL 1` which is IMHO more suitable (depends on your preferences though). Also works inside `(...)` code blocks but assumes commands never set negative errorlevels (never encountered one but is worth mentionning)

Normally setting a variable with the `set` command doesn't change the errorlevel so you can choose either one of the two options. But as I don't have a windows machine to test it right now, I'll play it safe and give you the first option. I'll edit my answer once I've tested the second option.

```
set exit_code=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %exit_code% NEQ 0 (  
    echo Error calling sqlplus, return code = %exit_code%
    exit /b %exit_code%
)
```

Some last advice: use [`exit /b`](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)
 instead of `exit`. `exit` will also exit the command line in batch

**EDIT** I've tested the second version and it works as well. So the code above can be replaced with:

```
set exit_code=%ERRORLEVEL%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (  
    echo Error calling sqlplus, return code = %exit_code%
    exit /b %exit_code%
)
```

[This blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743) explains quite well why this version should be used instead of the of the first one using the %ERRORLEVEL% variable.

Another option [@aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) kindly reminded me of in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808223/error-handling-in-bat-file/42810940#comment72747343_42810940) is the use of the [conditional executions operators `&&` and `||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

- `command1 && command2` will execute `command2` only if `command1` succeeded
- `command1 || command2` will execute `command2` only if `command1` failed.

Both operators use the exit code (in most cases the same as errorlevel but not always) to determine if a command failed or succeeded.

I've also seen you've posted your batch-file. There is a little something I'd like to point out though: `goto @ERROR_HANDLING_SQL` will throw an error because there is no label `@ERROR_HANDLING_SQL`. There exists a label `ERROR_HANDLING_SQL` at the end of your script though. If you were trying to jump to that label you should replace all occurences of `goto @ERROR_HANDLING_SQL` with `goto ERROR_HANDLING_SQL`

Comment: Thanks, do I need to reference my SQL script? So for example I have a script called Code.sql does that need to be referenced anywahere?

Comment: @E_McAndrew The answer I posted is only about the error handling (as your title mentions). The sql script you're executing using a [here-document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) must be executed otherwise in batch as batch doesn't support here-documents

Comment: My batch file runs the sql but I want to have error reporting for this. So is it not a case of using an if statement as you have answered in the same script?

Comment: @E_McAndrew you'll have to put the code in my answer just after your sql command as you want to have the error reporting of the sql.

Comment: Ok great, so I include this straight after where my SQL run and it doesn't actually need any say reference in the code to it?

Comment: @E_McAndrew no, no further reference is needed :-) the code above will always react to the errorlevel of the command executed just before it

Comment: Therefore, if I place it just after the SQL will it not report on that?

Comment: @E_McAndrew Yes it will report on that

Comment: In addition to `ErrorLevel`, there are the [conditional operators `&&` and `||`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), which allow to execute a command if the preceding one succeeded or failed, respectively; these check whether or not the exit code is zero...