# Error Writing to file in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a .bat file that would ask your name and save it in a .txt file. If the file already exists, I want it to say "Your Name is ____"

```
@echo off
if exist BatchfileOutput.txt (
cls
FOR /F %%i IN (BatchfileOutput.txt) DO echo Your name is %%i

) else (
echo What is your name?
set /p %name%= )
echo %name% > BatchfileOutput.txt

pause
```

It prints ECHO is off, probably due to @echo off at the top. If I manually add text to the file, it displays the text. Could anyone help me get around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch Variables Won't Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is `set /P name=` but not `set /P %name%=`.
2. The command `echo %name%` needs to be moved into the `else` block too. For this to work, [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) must be established:

   ```cmd
   @echo off
   if exist "BatchfileOutput.txt" (
       cls
       for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in ("BatchfileOutput.txt") do echo Your name is %%i
   ) else (
       echo What is your name?
       set /P name=
       setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
       > "BatchfileOutput.txt" echo !name!
       endlocal
   )
   pause
   ```

   I moved the [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) part to the front in order to avoid a trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to be output also.

   To avoid delayed expansion, you could avoid the parenthesised `else` block by using `goto :Label` as the last command of the `if` block, then omitting `else` and the parentheses, and then placing `:Label` before `pause`:

   ```cmd
   @echo off
   if exist "BatchfileOutput.txt" (
       cls
       for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in ("BatchfileOutput.txt") do echo Your name is %%i
       goto :Label
   )
   echo What is your name?
   set /P name=
   > "BatchfileOutput.txt" echo %name%
   :Label
   pause
   ```

I quoted all file paths and therefore used the `usebackq` option of [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) in order to avoid trouble with such strings containing white-spaces. Furthermore, I stated the `tokens=*` option for the `for /F` loop to read the full line even in case the name consists of multiple words.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
set /p name=
```

not

```
set /p %name%=
```

which would set the variable named *the current contents of NAME*