# Variables are disappering

Tags: batch-file

I need to have my code come out like this:

```
if %Psername%==admin ( 
    if %P%==password (
```

But when I put in the code:

```
echo( if %Psername%==admin ( >>"%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Orion\Login.bat"
echo(   if %P%==password ( >>"%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Orion\Login.bat"
```

it comes out as this in the text file:

```
if ==admin ( 
if ==password (
```

How to I `echo` the string `%Psername%` and `%P%` literally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch Variables Won't Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set) (assuming, of course, that you've actually set the variables in the first place somewhere higher up in the script that you just aren't showing us.)

Comment: To `echo` a literal `%` you need to use `%%` as `%` escapes `%` (ie turns it into an ordinary character). Other characters like `)`, `>`,`<` `=` and `|`  require `^` to be prefixed to be escaped.

Comment: @SomethingDark I have not set any variables as this code is going to be part of a downloader

Comment: You're writing a script to write a script? I wish you had mentioned that; you would have gotten a correct answer sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Magoo says, special characters need to be escaped. In this case, the percentage signs(`%`) require that.

Here is the fixed snippet:

```
echo( if %%Psername%%==admin ( >>"%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Orion\Login.bat"
echo(   if %%P%%==password ( >>"%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Orion\Login.bat"
```

And please check [this page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) for more information on special characters.