# BATCH. Using variable as folder name in path

Tags: batch-file

I have problem with batch. I want to create new dir and save file to it everytime batch is opened

This is sample of my code

```
SET i=0
FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,100) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST res\%%i (
        mkdir res\%%i
        GOTO run
    )
)
:run
start X.exe /stext res\%i%\X.txt
```

Creating folders works properly. I have problem with

```
start X.exe /stext res\%i%\X.txt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%i%` and `%%i` are totally different variables. `%i%` is a regular batch variable, while `%%i` only exists within the `for` loop. Once you call `goto run`, it no longer exists.

You can store `%%i` in a variable and then call it using [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set), because you're setting it inside of a code block (a set of parentheses).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET i=0
FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,100) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST res\%%i (
        set i=%%i
        mkdir res\!i!
        GOTO run
    )
)
:run
start X.exe /stext res\!i!\X.txt
```

Comment: But delayedexpansion is only needed when you output the var `i` inside the code block, setting works. So you could use `mkdir res\%%i` and omit delayedexpansion.

Comment: @LotPings - In this particular example, yes. But I was trying to avoid them coming back with a later, unrelated question about why their variable isn't updating inside of a for loop.