# Echo is off windows batch error

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-scripting

**Scenario**

I want that If user enters a value, I  get host name and If user do not enter any value then I just echo default path.

**Problem Statement**

After adding these conditions in if else I am getting **echo is off** if user enters a values.

How can i resolve this?

```
SET /P USER_INSTALL= Installation Path : 
@echo:
if "%USER_INSTALL%"=="" ( echo "------Default path------") else (
ECHO %USER_INSTALL%
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET HOST=%%i
ECHO %HOST%)
```

Comment: change  `SET /P USER_INSTALL= Installation Path :` to `SET /P "USER_INSTALL=Installation Path: "` see no spaces around equsl sign. also don't use `echo:` to echo a blank line, use either `echo/` or `echo(`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch Variables Won't Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set)

Comment: Also, it's batch, not bash

Comment: @elzooilogico The colon `:` serves the same as the `/` or `(` in an echo. The prompt in a set /p may have as much leading spaces as you like - they are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do, but try this:

```
@echo off
SET /P USER_INSTALL=Installation Path : 
if "%USER_INSTALL%"=="" goto IP1
goto :IP2

:IP1
echo "------Default path------"
PAUSE
exit

:IP2
ECHO %USER_INSTALL%
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET HOST=%%i
ECHO %HOST%
PAUSE
exit
```

This organizes the code a bit. I added pause commands so you can see what it is doing. When testing this, I am not getting an "echo is off" error. Please let me know if it works!