# Why the value of output variable not change inside loop - Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using the following code, and if I call the array.bat outside loop, you can the the value in output that is different, varying with the index that I used during call.

```
    @echo off

set empresas[0]=EPB
set empresas[1]=ENF
set empresas[2]=ESE
set empresas[3]=ESS
set empresas[4]=EBO
set empresas[5]=EMG
set empresas[6]=EMT
set empresas[7]=ETO

call array.bat len empresas length
call array.bat getitem empresas 0 empresa1
echo %empresa1%
call array.bat getitem empresas 1 empresa1
echo %empresa1%
echo %length%


for /l %%x in (0, 1, %length% ) do (

   call array.bat getitem empresas %x% empresa3

   echo %empresa3%
   echo %%x
)
```

That code generate the output:

```
   EPB
ENF
7
ETO
0
ETO
1
ETO
2
ETO
3
ETO
4
ETO
5
ETO
6
ETO
7
```

Only tha last value is being printted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch Variables Won't Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set)

Comment: It is not the same question. The value not change ONLY inside loop.

Comment: It is _exactly_ the same question. Variables that get set inside of code blocks don't get updated until the end of the code block unless delayed expansion is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delayedexpansion` trap again. Please search for `delayed expansion` on SO.

Try

```
call array.bat getitem empresas %%x empresa3

CALL echo %%empresa3%%
```

Note that `%%x` is the value of the metavariable `%%x`. `%x%` is the *content* of the *environment* variable `x` (which, according to your code, is undefined)

Reading about `delayedexpansion` will explain why the extra `CALL` and doubling of the `%` are required (one of many possible solutions)