# Command works on command line, but operates unexpectedly in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this simple batch code to check the Date Modified on a sub-folder (specifically the Recycle Bin.) 
This search works flawlessly when manually input in Command Prompt, but not batch.

And using the same exact code to check other folders it works just fine. Help?

Code:

```
if exist C:\$Recycle.Bin (
pushd "C:\$Recycle.Bin"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /S /b S-1-*-1001 /AD') do set {file}=%%a
for %%a in ("%{file}%") do echo Recycle Bin: %%~ta
popd
)
```

Comment: This lacks [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion), independent on whether you execute this code in `cmd` or in a batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is not working in batch is for one annoying feature of `IF` statements with the `SET` command. As stated by [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9681923/8667430) - "`cmd` expands variables when commands are parsed, not when they are run. It so happens that an `if` or `for` statement with a block `( ... )` (or actually any block) counds as a single command in that case. So when you set variables inside a block and try using them in the same block there are no variables anymore – they were replaced by the values the variables had before the block even executed." - [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey)

To fix this you can simply not put your code block inside the `IF` statement but rather use an `ELSE` and have it `goto` an `:EOF`

**Option 1:** - Avoid `IF` Statement *W/H* Code Block

```
@ECHO OFF

Rem | Check If Directory Exists & pushd It.
if exist "C:\$Recycle.Bin" (pushd "C:\$Recycle.Bin") ELSE (goto :EOF)

Rem | Grab data on folders
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /S /b S-1-*-1001 /AD') do (set "{File}=%%a")

Rem | Display data on folders
for %%a in ("%{file}%") do (echo Recycle Bin: %%~ta)

Rem | Un-pushd
popd

pause
goto :EOF
```

If you do however wish to use a block inside the `IF` statment you will need to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the top of your script. Furthermore, to echo or read brackets you will have to use `!{File}!` over `%{File}%`.

**Option 2:** - Properly expand `IF` Statement *W/H* Code Block

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if exist "C:\$Recycle.Bin" (

    pushd "C:\$Recycle.Bin"
    for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /S /b S-1-*-1001 /AD') do (set "{File}=%%a")
    for %%a in ("!{file}!") do (

        Set "data=%%~ta"
        echo Recycle Bin: !data!

    )
    popd

) Else (Goto :EOF)

pause
goto :EOF
```