# value is void in loop in .bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this code in which I want to obtain the subtraction of a day from the current date, from 0 to -10, but I only correctly obtain the last one that is out of the cycle, any idea why?

```
echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /L %%A IN (0,1,10) DO (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%t IN (`powershell -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Date).AddDays(-%%A).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd HH:MM:ss')"`) DO (SET "START_DATE=%%t")
    echo START_DATE: %START_DATE%
)
echo START_DATE: %START_DATE%
Endlocal



pause

PopD
exit
```

and what I get in the terminal is this

```
echo off
START_DATE:
START_DATE:
START_DATE:
START_DATE:
START_DATE:
START_DATE:
START_DATE:
START_DATE:
START_DATE:
START_DATE:
START_DATE:
START_DATE: 2020/07/22 11:07:06
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Batch Variables Won't Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set) You've enabled delayed expansion, but you aren't using it. Use `!START_DATE!` instead of `%START_DATE%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `delayedexpansion` which you already enabled, but don't `usebackq` either as it is not needed.

```
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /L %%A IN (0,1,10) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%t IN ('powershell -Command "(Get-Date).AddDays(-%%A).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd HH:MM:ss')"') DO (
    SET "START_DATE=%%t"
    echo START_DATE: !START_DATE!
 )
)
echo START_DATE: %START_DATE% 
Endlocal
pause
popd
exit
```

Note the `!` intead of `%`. Which tells the system which variable you want to expand.

As a side note, you could get away without `delayedexpansion` if you simply want to `echo` the date/time in the loop.

```
@echo off
FOR /L %%A IN (0,1,10) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%t IN ('powershell -Command "(Get-Date).AddDays(-%%A).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd HH:MM:ss')"') DO (
    SET "START_DATE=%%t"
    echo START_DATE: %%t
 )
)
echo START_DATE: %START_DATE% 
Endlocal
pause
PopD
exit
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought it was mandatory to declare this SET "START DATE = %% t"

Comment: well, no. You can simply use the metavariable, unless you move out of the loop to use the variable in other places.

Answer (score 0):

To get your required output in the `cmd.exe` window you don't need a [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) at all, just a single [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) one:

```batch-file
@"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile "for($i=0; $i -le 10; $i++){"(Get-Date).AddDays(-$i).ToString('START_DATE: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')}"
@Pause
```

If you need to run it from a [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop), because you need to perform additional work on each line of output then you should, once again, allow [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) to perform most of the heavy lifting:

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('^"
 "%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile^
 "for($i=0; $i -le 10; $i++){(Get-Date).AddDays(-$i).ToString(`"^
 "'START_DATE: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')}"^"')Do @Echo %%G
@Pause
```

---

This methodology could also be extended such that you can directly define the output as variables too, `%Now[-1]%`, `%Now[-2]%`, `%Now[-3]%` etc. This would give you a simple way to get your required format dates based upon the number of days ago; for example:

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('^"
 "%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile^
 "for($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++){(Get-Date).AddDays(-$i).ToString(`"^
 "\"Now[-$i]^=yyyy/MM/dd\")}"^"')Do @Set "%%G"
@Echo %Now[-6]%&Pause
```

*The last line is obviously included just to show you what one of the defined variables would output.*

Or based upon the simpler range method suggested by [@lit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447901/lit) in the comment section:

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('^"
 "%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile^
 "(0..-10)|%%{(Get-Date).AddDays($_).ToString(\"Now[$_]^=yyyy/MM/dd\")}"
 ^"')Do @Set "%%G"
@Echo %Now[0]%&Pause
```

Comment: Using a range would be even easier. `(0..-10) | ForEach-Object { (Get-Date).AddDays($_).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd HH:MM:ss') }`

Comment: Yes @lit, point taken, however as the question was not really about powershell, my intention was to show that the powershell command need not run ten times in order to `do` 10 things, rather than how to more efficiently use powershell. I have added an additional example to the bottom of my answer, using that method.

Answer (score 0):

This will not produce an array of environment variables like Compo's answer. But, I think it will do what the original question asked.

```
@"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
     "(0..-10) | ForEach-Object { (Get-Date).AddDays($_).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd') }"
@pause
```