# Python and PowerShell returning errors

Tags: python, excel, powershell

Edit to Post:

I have tested differently and now I am seeing the errors that I was seeing in Python in PowerShell. I changed from pasting the enitre script below into PowerShell, and am instead calling it directly with this command:

```
C:\temp\ExcelManipulation.ps1
```

When done this way in PowerShell, I see all the errors. Also, my excel file gets deleted.

---

I have written a PowerShell script using the [ImportExcel PowerShell Module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) that will open an existing excel created from SQL and add a lot of formatting. I can confirm that the script I wrote works, and I am seeing what I want to see on the formatted excel file.

However, because of reasons outside of my control, I am not able to call the PowerShell script directly. Instead, I have a Python script that will open PowerShell and run the script. The problem ends up being that when calling the script through Python, I am getting errors returned in Python on several lines saying:

> The property 'HorizontalAlignment' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

or

> The property 'Bold' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

These Errors are not appearing if I run the PowerShell script without Python and I am getting my expected excel output. I am at a bit of a loss on what could be causing this. My python script is very simple:

```
import subprocess
import sys
p = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', "-File", 'C:\\ExcelManipulation2\\ExcelManipulation.ps1'], stdout=sys.stdout)
```

My PowerShell script is currently built for a static file:

```
#Load Excel File, Location will be dynamic
$ExcelData = Open-ExcelPackage C:\ExcelManipulation2\ExcelTest.xlsx
#rowCount is following the header row
$runningRowCount = 1
#declare what sheet we are editing and rename it
$sheet1 = $ExcelData.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"]
$sheet1.Name ="Emp Credit Export"
#Get Column Count
$columnCount = $sheet1.Dimension.Columns
$rowcount = $sheet1.Dimension.Rows
$staticRowCount = $sheet1.Dimension.Rows
$alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
[string]$global:ColumnLetter = $null
[string]$global:cellValue = $null
$LongestColumn = 0
$grandTotalCountColumn = 'Last Name'
$grandTotalSubtotalColumns = @('Hired', 'Screened', 'Eligible', 'eSigned',  'Needs 8850', 'Late 8850')
$dateHeaderExceptions = @('Last PPED', 'DOB', 'Most Recent Payroll PPED', 'Latest PPED', 'First Time on Payroll', 'Sow Expiration', 'WOTC Program Start', 'WOTC Program End', 'LTU Program Start', 'LTU Program End', 'IEC Program Start', 'IEC Program End', 'NYY Program Start', 'NYY Program End', 'TOS Program Start', 'TOS Program End', 'TX TANF Program Start', 'TX TANF Program End', 'SC TANF Program Start', 'SC TANF Program End')
$falsePositveDateHeaders = @('WOTC Wages to Date', 'Blank Original Start Date', 'Blank DOB', 'Invalid DOB', 'Term Date less than start date', 'Rehire date less than start date', 'Blank Term Dates', 'Blank Rehire Dates', 'Rehire dates equal to start dates','Changing Start Date', 'Start Date after PPED', 'Gave Info Date Calculation', 'Job Offer Date Calculation', 'Hire Date Calculation')

function GetColumnLetter($columnNumber){
    if ($columnNumber -gt 26) 
    {
        $runningColumnCount = $columnNumber
        $loopCount = 0
        while ($runningColumnCount -gt 26) 
        {
            $runningColumnCount = $runningColumnCount - 26
            $loopCount++
        }
        #Get First Letter
        $subStringIndex = $loopCount-1
        $splitString = $alphabet.Substring($subStringIndex)
        $columnLetter1 = $splitString.Substring(0,1)
        #Get Second Letter
        $subStringIndex = $runningColumnCount-1
        $splitString = $alphabet.Substring($subStringIndex)
        $columnLetter2 = $splitString.Substring(0,1)
        #Combine Column Letters
        $global:ColumnLetter = $columnLetter1+$columnLetter2
    } 
    else 
    {
        $subStringIndex = $columnNumber-1
        $splitString = $alphabet.Substring($subStringIndex)
        $global:ColumnLetter = $splitString.Substring(0,1)
    }
}

#Insert Blank Row 
$sheet1.InsertRow(1, 1) #this insert a row at the top of the worksheet
$runningRowCount++
$rowcount++

#Insert Filter (If applicable)
$sheet1.InsertRow(1, 1)
$sheet1.Cells["a1"].Value = 'Create Date Time:'
$sheet1.Cells["b1"].Value = '10/30/1960'
$sheet1.Cells["a1:b1"].Style.Font.Bold = $true
$runningRowCount++
$rowcount++

#Insert Run Date
$sheet1.InsertRow(1, 1)
$sheet1.Cells["a1"].Value = 'Run Date:'
$sheet1.Cells["b1"].Value = '10/05/2023'
$sheet1.Cells["a1:b1"].Style.Font.Bold = $true
$runningRowCount++
$rowcount++

#Insert Screen Date Range
$sheet1.InsertRow(1, 1)
$sheet1.Cells["a1"].Value = 'Screen Date Range:'
$sheet1.Cells["b1"].Value = 'Unbound'
$sheet1.Cells["a1:b1"].Style.Font.Bold = $true
$runningRowCount++
$rowcount++

#Insert Start Date Range
$sheet1.InsertRow(1, 1)
$sheet1.Cells["a1"].Value = 'Start Date Range:'
$sheet1.Cells["b1"].Value = '10/05/2022 - Unbound'
$sheet1.Cells["a1:b1"].Style.Font.Bold = $true
$runningRowCount++
$rowcount++

#Insert Corp Name
$sheet1.InsertRow(1, 1)
$sheet1.Cells["a1"].Value = 'This is a long corp name'
$sheet1.Cells["a1"].Style.Font.Bold = $true
$sheet1.Cells["a1"].Style.Font.Size = 13
$runningRowCount++
$rowcount++

#insert subtotal thing
$sheet1.Cells["c1"].Value = 'This is a long subtotal name'
$sheet1.Cells["c2"].Value = '100'
$sheet1.Cells["c2"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = 'Center'
$sheet1.Cells["c1:c2"].Style.Font.Bold = $true

#Format header row
GetColumnLetter $columnCount #fetch column Letter for below portion
$sheet1.Cells["a"+$runningRowCount+":"+$global:ColumnLetter+$runningRowCount].Style.Font.Bold = $true
$sheet1.Cells["a"+$runningRowCount+":"+$global:ColumnLetter+$runningRowCount].Style.Fill.PatternType = 'Solid'
$sheet1.Cells["a"+$runningRowCount+":"+$global:ColumnLetter+$runningRowCount].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(0, 196, 196, 205)
$sheet1.Cells["a"+$runningRowCount+":"+$global:ColumnLetter+$runningRowCount].AutoFilter = $true
$headerRow = $runningRowCount
$runningRowCount++
$sheet1.View.FreezePanes($runningRowCount, 1)

#Find and remove R3pl@c3 from columns and resize columns
$internalColumnCount = 1
for(($i = 0); $i -lt $columnCount; $i++)
{
    GetColumnLetter $internalColumnCount
    
    if($internalColumnCount -le 2)
    {
        $x = 1
        for(($j = 0); $j -le $headerRow; $j++)
        {
            if($sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$x].Value.length -gt $LongestColumn)
            {
                if($sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$x].Style.Font.Size -eq 13)
                {
                    $LongestColumn = $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$x].Value.length
                    $y = 0
                }
                else 
                {
                    $LongestColumn = $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$x].Value.length
                    $y = 1
                }
            }
            $x++
        }
        if($y -eq 0)
        {
            $sheet1.Column($internalColumnCount).Width = $LongestColumn+6
        }
        else
        {
            $sheet1.Column($internalColumnCount).Width = $LongestColumn+4
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $test = $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+"1"].Value.length
        if($test -lt 2)
        {
            if(($sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$headerRow].Value -eq "SSN") -or ($sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$headerRow].Value -eq "VRID"))
            {
                $sheet1.Column($internalColumnCount).Width = 11
            }
            else 
            {
                $length = $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$headerRow].Value.length
                $sheet1.Column($internalColumnCount).Width = $length+4
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            $topRowLength = $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+"1"].Value.length
            $headerRowLength = $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$headerRow].Value.length
            if($topRowLength -gt $headerRowLength)
            {
                $sheet1.Column($internalColumnCount).Width = $topRowLength+4
            }
            else
            {
                $sheet1.Column($internalColumnCount).Width = $headerRowLength+4
            }
        }
    }

    if($sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$runningRowCount].Value -like "R3pl@c3*")
    {
        $internalRowCount = $runningRowCount
        for(($j = 1); $j -lt $staticRowCount; $j++)
        {
            $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$internalRowCount].Value = $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$internalRowCount].Value.Substring(7)
            $internalRowCount++
        }    
    }
    
    if($global:ColumnLetter -eq 'A')
    {
        $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow].Value = 'Grand Total'
        $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow].Style.HorizontalAlignment = 'Left'
        $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow].Style.Font.Bold = $true
    }
    
    $global:cellValue = $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+($runningRowCount-1)].Value
    
    if(($global:cellValue -like "*Date*" -or $dateHeaderExceptions.Contains($global:cellValue)) -and $falsePositveDateHeaders -notcontains $global:cellValue)
    {
       Set-ExcelColumn -Worksheet $sheet1 -Column $internalColumnCount -NumberFormat 'Short Date'
    }
    
    $subtotalRow = $rowcount + 2
    
    if($grandTotalCountColumn -eq $global:cellValue)
    {
        [string]$countFormula = 'COUNTA('+$global:ColumnLetter+$runningRowCount+':'+$global:ColumnLetter+$rowcount
        $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow].Formula = '=COUNTA('+$global:ColumnLetter+$runningRowCount+':'+$global:ColumnLetter+$rowcount+')'
        $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow].Style.HorizontalAlignment = 'Right'
        $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow].Style.Font.Bold = $true
    }
    
    $percentRow = $rowcount + 3
    
    if(($grandTotalSubtotalColumns.Contains('Hired') -and $global:ColumnLetter -eq 'L') -or ($grandTotalSubtotalColumns.Contains('Hired') -and $global:ColumnLetter -eq 'L'))
    {
        $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow].Formula = '=SUBTOTAL(9,'+$global:ColumnLetter+$runningRowCount+':'+$global:ColumnLetter+$rowcount+')'
        $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$percentrow].Formula = '=IF(COUNTA('+$global:ColumnLetter+$runningRowCount+':'+$global:ColumnLetter+$rowcount+')=0,"0%",IF(AND(100*('+$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow+'/'+$countFormula+'))>0,100*('+$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow+'/COUNTA('+$global:ColumnLetter+$runningRowCount+':'+$global:ColumnLetter+$rowcount+'))<=1),"1%",IF(AND(100*('+$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow+'/COUNTA('+$global:ColumnLetter+$runningRowCount+':'+$global:ColumnLetter+$rowcount+'))>=99,100*('+$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow+'/COUNTA('+$global:ColumnLetter+$runningRowCount+':'+$global:ColumnLetter+$rowcount+'))<100),"99%",IF(100*('+$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow+'/COUNTA('+$global:ColumnLetter+$runningRowCount+':'+$global:ColumnLetter+$rowcount+'))=100,"100%",ROUND(100*('+$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow+'/COUNTA('+$global:ColumnLetter+$runningRowCount+':'+$global:ColumnLetter+$rowcount+')),0)&"%"))))'
        $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow].Style.HorizontalAlignment = 'Right'
        $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$percentrow].Style.HorizontalAlignment = 'Right'
        $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow].Style.Font.Bold = $true
        $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$percentrow].Style.Font.Bold = $true
    }

    $internalColumnCount++
}

Close-ExcelPackage $ExcelData
```

Is there any ideas on why Python would be seeing these errors but PowerShell is not?

Here is the full list of errors that are being returned in Python.

```
The property 'HorizontalAlignment' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\ExcelManipulation2\ExcelManipulation.ps1:189 char:9
+         $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow].Style.Horizo ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

The property 'Bold' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\ExcelManipulation2\ExcelManipulation.ps1:190 char:9
+         $sheet1.Cells[$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow].Style.Font.B ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Exception calling "Column" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At C:\ExcelManipulation2\ExcelManipulation.ps1:139 char:13
+             $sheet1.Column($internalColumnCount).Width = $LongestColu ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException

Exception calling "Column" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At C:\ExcelManipulation2\ExcelManipulation.ps1:167 char:17
+ ...             $sheet1.Column($internalColumnCount).Width = $topRowLengt ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException

Exception calling "Column" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At C:\ExcelManipulation2\ExcelManipulation.ps1:158 char:17
+ ...                $sheet1.Column($internalColumnCount).Width = $length+4
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException

Exception calling "Column" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At C:\ExcelManipulation2\ExcelManipulation.ps1:153 char:17
+                 $sheet1.Column($internalColumnCount).Width = 11
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException
```

Comment: Those errors are from Powershell, not Python.

Comment: Yes, however, these errors only happen when calling ExcelManipulation.ps1 from Python. If I run the script directly in PowerShell, I get the expected output.

Comment: What is the exact command when you run this directly in powershell?

Comment: In the original post it is the code snippet under "My PowerShell script is currently built for a static file:"

Comment: I understand that.  I asked for **the actual exact command** that you use to run it.  Are you using the same exact command that is in the python code, i.e. `powershell.exe -File C:\ExcelManipulation2\ExcelManipulation.ps1` ?

Comment: When I call python, the command that I use is 
`import subprocess
import sys
p = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', "-File", 'C:\\ExcelManipulation2\\ExcelManipulation.ps1'], stdout=sys.stdout)`

Comment: I feel like you don't understand my question.  When you run this **in powershell**, what is the exact full command?  What do you literally type at the command prompt?

Comment: I see, I did not, and I am not sure I still fully understand, so I will give more context. I am using Decisions (Low Code platform) that runs the Python script, then Python would call the PowerShell script. When I am doing local testing on just the PowerShell script, I have been using Visual Studio Code to write and test it. When I test directly in PowerShell, I paste the entire PowerShell script. I am not calling ExcelManipulation.ps1, I literally copy and paste it in the terminal.

Comment: Are you sure `powershell.exe -File ...` is correct syntax?  The examples I see on the web use `-command` instead of `-File`.

Comment: I think it is. But I tried with -command and without -File and got the same results. However what you said got me thinking and I tried to just call the PowerShell script from PowerShell by using the command `C:\temp\ExcelManipulatiop.ps1` and got the same errors that I am seeing when running it from Python. So now the issue is there is a difference when pasting the entire script in PowerShell vs calling it. I am updating the original post with this.

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 errors provided appear to happen because the Cells index, `$global:ColumnLetter+$subtotalRow`, contains a variable that is not created until later on line 200: `$subtotalRow`.

When the script is run in VSCode, the variable might already be set from a previous run. Running the script by command (or Python) would start with a blank slate.

As a test, in VSCode, add `Remove-Variable -Name * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the start of script. This will clear any existing variables in VSCode, allowing it to run in a condition closer to how it runs when called from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Different behaviors between Python and PowerShell and even PowerShell ISE and PowerShell terminal can be attributed to difference of 32/64 bitness. Most Windows machines ship with both PowerShell versions installed but external softwares including Python are installed in a specific bit version.

My guess is you tested coded in a 32-bit PowerShell ISE which worked but running the script at command line in a 64-bit Python and 64-bit PowerShell terminal failed. Alternatively, vice-versa of bitness in above scenario.

**PowerShell ISE**

[image: PowerShell ISE Screenshot]

When you copy and paste code, you are using the graphical interface application as shown above with editor and console to run PowerShell code interactively. Since all code works here without error, your `ExcelPackage` may be installed correctly in this bitness version. If you had to search for this program via Window start to open and use, multiple versions will result. Any `x86` in title of program (see also menu bar) denotes 32-bit version, otherwise 64-bit. Alternatively, see below link to check bitness in the ISE console.

**PowerShell/CMD Terminals**

[image: CMD/PowerShell Terminals]

When running PowerShell scripts at command line with `powershell.exe`, you are using the blue box terminal or black box CMD terminal. Again, if searching for this terminal via Window start, multiple versions may show up where `x86` indicates the 32-bit version and other one the 64-bit version. If you ran `powershell.exe` in the CMD black box terminal, by default CMD will call the corresponding PS version that shares its own installed bitness. To check bitness in PowerShell, see this post [Determine if current PowerShell Process is 32-bit or 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8588960/1422451) For CMD, see [batch file to check 64bit or 32bit OS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12322308/1422451).

**Python `subprocess` Call**

Python's `subprocess` call mimics a command line call in the corresponding bitness that Python is installed to. Therefore, if Python bitness version does not align to working code of PowerShell bitness, the `.ps1` code will ultimately fail. Do note: you may have multiple Python versions installed on same machine (i.e., 2.7 vs 3.4 vs 3.10, or Anaconda versions) called differently by IDEs like VSCode, Jupiter or Sypder. To check bitness in whatever Python environment you attempt `subprocess`, see this post: [How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit)